# VHDL output declarations with State machine

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to write a state machine in VHDL that will scan a 4x4 keypad.  I want keyP set to 0 at the start and after a Reset.  I also want the `Col` to be set to "1111" at the start and after a Reset.

As I'm not fully versed in VHDL programming I'm sure it's just a stupid syntax error.
The error I get is:

> Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Col[0]" at Lab_7_Keypad.vhd(39) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

and the same for `Col[1]`, `Col[2]`, `Col[3]`, and for `keyP` as well.

Here's my code for the start of it all.  Can someone give me an idea where I've gone wrong?

Thanks

```
ENTITY Lab_7_Keypad IS
PORT(
    nReset          :   IN  STD_LOGIC;
    clk             :   IN  STD_LOGIC;
    row             :   IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    Col             :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    data            :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    keyP            :   OUT STD_LOGIC);

    END Lab_7_Keypad;

ARCHITECTURE a OF Lab_7_Keypad IS   
TYPE STATE_TYPE IS ( Col1Set, Col2Set, Col3Set, Col4Set );
SIGNAL  coltest :   STATE_TYPE;

BEGIN
PROCESS (clk, nReset )
BEGIN
    keyP <= '0';
    Col <= "1111";
    IF nReset = '0' THEN                        --  asynch Reset to zero
        coltest <=  Col1Set;
        Col <="1111";
        keyP <= '0';
    ELSIF clk'EVENT AND clk = '1' THEN          --  triggers on PGT

        CASE coltest IS
            WHEN Col1Set => 
            Col <="1110";
                CASE row IS
                    WHEN    "1110"=>--row 1
                    data <= "0001";
                    keyP <= '1';
                    WHEN    "1101"=>--row 2
                    data <= "0100";
                    keyP <= '1';
                    WHEN    "1011"=>--row 3
                    data <= "0111";
                    keyP <= '1';
                    WHEN    "0111"=>--row 4
                    data <= "1110";
                    keyP <= '1';
                    WHEN OTHERS => coltest <= Col2Set;
                END CASE;
  --And continues with same Case statements three more times.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your synthesis error is due to the fact that you are assigning to both **col** and **keyP** outside of the asynchronous reset or clock edge of your process, this does not correctly describe a register. Remove these assignments and the errors should go away.

```
PROCESS (clk, nReset )
BEGIN
    --keyP <= '0';  <------- BAD!
    --Col <= "1111"; <------- BAD!
    IF nReset = '0' THEN                        --  asynch Reset to zero
        coltest <=  Col1Set;
        Col <="1111";
        keyP <= '0';
    ELSIF clk'EVENT AND clk = '1' THEN          --  triggers on PGT

        CASE coltest IS
            WHEN Col1Set => 
            Col <="1110";
                CASE row IS
                    WHEN    "1110"=>--row 1
                    data <= "0001";
                    keyP <= '1';
                    WHEN    "1101"=>--row 2
                    data <= "0100";
                    keyP <= '1';
                    WHEN    "1011"=>--row 3
                    data <= "0111";
                    keyP <= '1';
                    WHEN    "0111"=>--row 4
                    data <= "1110";
                    keyP <= '1';
                    WHEN OTHERS => coltest <= Col2Set;
                END CASE;
  --And continues with same Case statements three more times.
```